# Is it possible to call an IBAction UIButton from another view?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and programming in general. I'm working on an app I didn't write, and am struggling to understand the existing code. To avoid dealing with protocol errors, I want to know if it's possible to reuse the functionality of a UIButtons IBAction on one view and call it's IBAction function in another view. If so How would I go about doing this. Your help is appreciated!

ContextScreen
https://controlc.com/1a91efca
(the button I'm trying to reuse)ContextMenuScreenViewController [a https://controlc.com/90847f01
the original location of the buttonOrderCreateViewController [a https://:controlc.com/3b52eefc

[the original location of the refer order button(OrderCreateViewController)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BwyU.jpg)

[ContextMenuScreenController: where I'd like to reuse the refer order button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OefPl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy can easily move the logic from IBAction to som function and call this function in IBAction and from any View what you need!

Comment: also, you can provide some code, and I will try to help you on a real project

Comment: Thank you but is there something I must alter first, when I try to reuse this button(as I want it to route to the same location)I. receive the error:
 _unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff066ecdf40_

my button is:   `@IBAction func referOrder(_ sender: UIButton) {
        viewOutput?.onReferOrder()`
    
    }'

Comment: you need to provide some code because right know is it impossible to understand how you need to reuse your button and etc. Can you add some code, please?

Comment: thank you, sorry I'll try and provide better context
PhotoViewer
`extension PhotoViewerScreenViewController: ContextMenuScreenModuleOutput {
    func createOrderFromPhoto() {
        
        guard let id = self.viewOutput?.mediaIds[self.rootView.pagesData.currentNumberOfPage ] else { return }
        if let media = MediaService.mediaFile(for: id), let file = media.file {
            self.viewOutput?.createOrder(forMedia:file)
        }
        else if let media = MediaService.media(for: id), let file = media.file {
            self.viewOutput?.createOrder(forMedia:file) }}}`

Comment: sorry for the indentation I will put the rest in snippets

Comment: you can edit you question and add code to he snippet, not here. And you need to provide full code of controller, right now it is so messy

Comment: ContextScreen
_https://controlc.com/1a91efca_
 _(the button I'm trying to reuse)ContextMenuScreenViewController_
https://controlc.com/90847f01
_the original location of the buttonOrderCreateViewController_
https://controlc.com/3b52eefc

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your patience. This is my first stack-overflow post, still trying to get the formatting right.